# how to exclude retyping same parameters in extending classes

Tags: java

I would like to know if its possible to not retype all parameters to constructor, to make it more automatically. Some example:

```
abstract Class A {
int int1;
int int2;

A(int i1,int i2)
{
int1=i1;
int2=i2;
}}

Class B extends A{
int int3;
int int4;

B(int i1,int i2, int i3, int i4)
{
super(i1,i2);
int3=i3;
int4=i4;
}}

Class C extends B {
int int5;
int int6;

C(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6)
{
super(i1,i2,i3,i4);
int5=i5;
int6=i6;
}}
```

so is it possible to make less to type than repeating int1, int2, int3 etc? to make constructor of C class this way (or somehow simmilar):

```
class C extends B
{
int int5;
int int6;

C(super(),int i5, int i6)  // ??
{
super()  // ??
int5=i5;
int6=i6;
}}
```

and while creating object C do that this way:

```
C c = new C(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

and i would like to give constructor knowledge that first 4 parameters belongs to that super() class, that referencing to constructor B (super(),i3,i4) and this one super() reference of B constructor referencing to constructor of A (i1,i2)

Comment: Will a solution using `var-args` answer your question?

Comment: hmm not really i just want to get rid of those long lines in constructors, want to make it more clearly to read i want to know some 'shortcut' to not retype all those things over and over

Comment: Maybe the builder pattern will help you